# How to replace characters after certain word using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

Is there a way to find and replace characters after a certain word. In this example I want to replace only quotes that appear after the word (text:)  Every thing before (text:) should be ignored.

{Here is my text: "The quick "red fox" jumped over the "lazy dog" and it was fun"}

I know how to find and replace quotes, but how do I apply this to parts of the string after a certain word?

The end result should be this:

{Here is my text: The quick red fox jumped over the lazy dog and it was fun}

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a particularly good use case for regex. I would recommend simply splitting the string first before processing it.

```js
var str = 'Here is my text: "The quick "red fox" jumped over the "lazy dog" and it was fun"';

var parts = str.split('text:');

var final = parts[0] + 'text:' + parts[1].replace(/"/g, '');

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Excellent.  Many thanks :)  How can this be applied in Sublime?